# error from the controller not coming to view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

```
    if (user.UserName == DbData.UserName && DbData.Password.Equals(user.Password, tringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                   //redirect to main page //this is working fine
}

    else {
      ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Username/Password not matching");
   ViewBag.Message = ModelState["Error"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
  return View();
    }
```

and in View i wrote

```
@if(ViewBag.Message != null){
```

ViewBag.Message

}

but the error in the viewbag is not coming on the view

Comment: `ModelState` is discarded when you return View since you're not passing a model into it --  does `TempData["Error"]` have a value?

Comment: "Username/Password not matching"
This string will be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, if you check the TempData["Error"] in the immediate window, you'll see that it's null.
You need to give something to the view bag to get something in the view side.

**UPDATE**:
This will give you your message (
"Username/Password not matching") that you can set it to the ViewBag.

```
ModelState["Error"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage
```

Hope this solves your problem.

For your Info:
ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError Method (String, Exception):
Adds the specified model error to the errors collection for the model-state dictionary that is associated with the specified key.
from [ModelState.AddModelError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492511(v=vs.118).aspx)

**UPDATE**: 
To display the message in the View use the @ sign before the ViewBag.Message

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.Message))
{
@ViewBag.Message
}
```

Comment: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error);
This is not showing the value in the view

Comment: Please remove this: ViewBag.error = TempData["Error"]; and replaced with ViewBag.error = "Plain text"; then let us know if the ViewBag is still empty. As I said in my answer above, you're not setting a proper value in the ViewBag. If "Plain text" is displayed in the view, then try to provide the modelState error as I described above. Good luck!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as answer and vote for it. thanks

Comment: iam getting the data through that but on view the data in the Viewbag is not Rendering

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line in the view:@if(ViewBag.Message != null){ and then in the immediate window write this:ViewBag.Message and press enter. Tell me what's the value that is displayed.

Comment: Nothingnis comin up but i can see the message in viewbag when i add a watcch and still i cannot see error message on view

Comment: Did the breakpoint in the VIEW get hit ? if yes, please confirm what's inside the viewbag by looking at the value in the immediate window for example. It's important that you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: it is hitting the breakpoint and showing the message inside the viewbag correctly but still not showing